# Delphi datatype for SQL Server last_user_update

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi

The SQL Server code below returns the time-date of the last update to a table (any row.)

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TableName') 
AND (Index_ID = 1)
```

If I use this in a `TFDQuery`, what is the datatype `FDQuery1.FieldByName('last_user_update')`?

If I want to store and compare this value at different times in a Delphi variable, what Delphi datatype should I assign it to, Double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `TDateTime` for this.
Although the `TDateTime` is represented internally by a double you don't use a double because you'll miss out on all the date/time support.

The code goes like this.

```
var
  LastUpdate: TDateTime;
begin
  //Do query etc.
  ...
  LastUpdate:= MyQuery.FieldByName('last_user_update').AsDateTime;
```

Note that SQL server 7 and before do not have support for `TDate`. So if you just want the date part this code will fail in SQL server 7.

```
  LastUpdate:= MyQuery.FieldByName('last_user_update').AsDate;
```

Just get the full DateTime and strip of the Time part later.
However, you're working with 2008 so just extracting the date will work fine for you.

Here's a list of DateTime functions: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/ByFunction.asp?Main=DatesAndTimes